# Are there any benefits of calling an SFC function within the render method?

Tags: reactjs

I am working with the `react-gsap` library, and want to encapsulate specific `<Tween>` instances that do not need any props, because they are occuring multiple times in the same way.

Lets take a simple example of an instance, that doesn't need any props or state at all. Let's say this line

```
<Tween
   to={{opacity: 0}}
   duration={5}
/>
```

occurs really often in our code base, and we want to abstract it.

My first idea was to just create an SFC for that:

```
const HideTween = () => (
    <Tween to={{ opacity: 0 }} duration={5} />
);
// and then ...
<HideTween />
```

but that seems not to work at all. The Tweens are simply not showing any effect.

I then came up with another idea (which i personally dislike) to just call the SFC. Instead of `<HideTween />` , we now have

```
{HideTween()}
```

and voila, it works...

I am specifically curious now, why my first idea did not work at all. The question is not aimed into the `gsap` library directly, but more of a general form: Where, when and how can such an approach (of abstracting parts of your `render` into own functions) fail? If it is the library, how does it even achieve such a behaviour?
And why does it seem to work, when i call the function directly (i know this is kind of a bad approach)? Without any state or props present,
shouldn't `<HideTween />` have the same effect on every render as `{HideTween()}`?

**EDIT**
[Here is a minimal example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7u2hxu?file=index.js)

Exchange `<Tweens />` in line 38 with the content of the `Tweens` SFC, and you will see the animation again.

Comment: IMHO with <HiddenTween/> you crate one more layer in VDOM, on the other hand with just calling function VDOM is the same. So meybe there is some parent component which get tweens directly as child and do something with them? (just guessing)

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a bad example.. I also suspect the library to do some sort of checking, if specifically `<Tween>` components are present. But even if, how would you achieve this "check"? And why are they doing it in the first place?

Comment: Maybe, you can just set `defaultProps` in your `Tween` component and avoid this.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia Hmm, so what specifically would you set where? In the sandboxed example, we don't even have any props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share the same elements between different render methods by creating them ahead of the render cycle as you tried to do:

```
const HideTween = <Tween to={{ opacity: 0 }} duration={5} />
```

and then directly using the element (not instance) in the render methods:

```
<Timeline>
  {HideTween}
</Timeline>
```

`<Component />` is JSX sugar for creating an element of a react component. So your first idea didn't work as it would return an element returning an element of a Tween and not directly the Tween element. For usual DOM rendering this will work as expected, though. The second example works as you get the Tween element this way, but you're right to dislike it as it simply adds an unnecessary indirection.

Doing it this way you might think that react will reuse the same instance of the component in different places, but it will actually instantiate the component anew for each usage. Here is an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rzq5q5?file=index.js

I assume this is intentional as sharing the same instance of a component seems to be quite a rare use case and with stateful components the state would be shared as well synchronising components in different parts of the app (which could end up being quite confusing).

Also check out this article on the difference between components, elements and instances (instances will be created by react for you): [React Components, Elements, and Instances](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/react-components-elements-and-instances-90800811f8ca)

Here I've set up a simple example trying out a few things: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rzq5q5?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

In your Tween component:

```
class Tween extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    to: {opacity: 0},
    duration: 5
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: But the Tween component is coming out of the library:
`import { Tween, Timeline, SplitWords, SplitLetters, Controls } from 'react-gsap';`
I'm afraid this is not possible that way.